# image rotation with JQuery and HTML5 range input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, rotation

HTML5 *range input*, and a rotation plugin *jqueryrotate*
https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

the thing is i want the image to be rotated as soon as i change the value of the range element
i got to change a

element but for some weird reason it doesn't apply to the rotation value

my code :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $("#rotationrange").change(function  () {
        var rotationrange = $("#rotationrange").val();
        parseInt(rotationrange,10);
        var angle = rotationrange;
        $(".rotatebox").rotate(angle);
        $("p").text(angle);
       })
    });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
   <img src="assets/imgs/temp.jpg" height="480" width="640" class="rotatebox" />
   <input type="range" name="points" min="-20" max="20" id="rotationrange">
   <p>here</p> degrees
```

and the out put is that the

elements changes but the rotation never happened

any suggestions ?? maybe other plugin would work ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine

```
parseInt(rotationrange,10);
var angle = rotationrange;
```

into

```
var angle = parseInt(rotationrange, 10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Vzpng/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `parseInt` line.

```
parseInt(rotationrange,10);
```

`parseInt` does not alter the value of the variable inside the brackets; it outputs a new value as its return value. Therefore your line above will parse the value as an integer, but will then immediately throw away the result.

What you need to do is use that output, probably to write it back to the `rotationrange` variable, like this:

```
rotationrange = parseInt(rotationrange,10);
```

Hope that helps.